# Webpack generating empty bundle file

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, gulp, webpack-stream

I am trying to use webpack/webpack-stream to bundle some javascript files. The challenge I am having is that webpack generates the bundle.js file, but it is empty.
I have included the full details of the file here because I am not sure what I missed.
I am using webpack 5.
This works when I set the mode to development.

```
import filepath from 'path';
import gulp, { parallel } from 'gulp';
import yargs from 'yargs';
import cleanCss from 'gulp-clean-css';
import gulpif from 'gulp-if';
import sourcemaps from 'gulp-sourcemaps';
import imagemin from 'gulp-imagemin';
import del from 'del';
import webpackStream from 'webpack-stream';
import webpack from 'webpack';

const sass = require('gulp-sass')(require('sass'));
const PRODUCTION = yargs.argv.prod;

const path = {
  styles: {
    src: ['src/assets/scss/bundle.scss', 'src/assets/scss/admin.scss'],
    dest: 'dist/assets/css/',
  },
  images: {
    src: 'src/assets/images/**/*.{jpg,png,gif,svg,jpeg}',
    dest: 'dist/assets/images/',
  },
  scripts: {
    src: 'src/assets/js/bundle.js',
    dest: 'dist/assets/js',
  },
  others: {
    src: [
      'src/assets/**/*',
      'src/assets/{js,scss,images}',
      'src/assets/{js,scss,images}/**/*',
    ],
    dest: 'dist/assets/',
  },
};

const webpackConfig = {
  entry: {
    main: filepath.resolve(__dirname, './src/assets/js/bundle.js'),
  },
  output: {
    path: filepath.resolve(__dirname, './dist/assets/js/'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
  },
  mode: "production",
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: ['@babel/preset-env']
          },
        },
      }
    ]
  }
}

export const clean = () => del(['dist']);

export const styles = (cb) => {
  return gulp
    .src(path.styles.src)
    .pipe(gulpif(!PRODUCTION, sourcemaps.init()))
    .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(gulpif(PRODUCTION, cleanCss({ compatibility: 'ie8' })))
    .pipe(gulpif(!PRODUCTION, sourcemaps.write()))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(path.styles.dest));
  cb();
};

export const images = (cb) => {
  return gulp
    .src(path.images.src)
    .pipe(gulpif(PRODUCTION, imagemin()))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(path.images.dest));
  cb();
};

export const watch = () => {
  gulp.watch('src/assets/scss/**/*.scss', styles);
  gulp.watch(path.images.src, images);
  gulp.watch(path.others.src, copy);
};

export const copy = () => {
  return gulp.src(path.others.src).pipe(gulp.dest(path.others.dest));
};

export const scripts = () => {
  return gulp.src(path.scripts.src)
    .pipe(webpackStream(webpackConfig, webpack))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(path.scripts.dest));
};

export const build = gulp.series(clean, gulp.parallel(styles, images, copy));
export const build_dev = gulp.series(
  clean,
  gulp.parallel(styles, images, copy),
  watch
);

exports.default = build_dev;
```

Answer (score 2):

So I found what the problem was. I did not export my function. In webpack 5 only exported functions are transpiled

Instead of this

```
const testFunc = () => {
  console.log("we tested")
}
```

Do this

```
export const testFunc = () => {
  console.log("we tested")
}
```